# Exit code of variable assignment to command substitution in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, exit-code

I am confused about what error code the command will return when executing a variable assignment plainly and with command substitution:

```
a=$(false); echo $?
```

It outputs `1`, which let me think that variable assignment doesn't sweep or produce new error code upon the last one. But when I tried this:

```
false; a=""; echo $?
```

It outputs `0`, obviously this is what `a=""` returns and it override `1` returned by `false`.

I want to know why this happens, is there any particularity in variable assignment that differs from other normal commands? Or just be cause `a=$(false)` is considered to be a single command and only command substitution part make sense?

**-- UPDATE --**

Thanks everyone, from the answers and comments I got the point "When you assign a variable using command substitution, the exit status is the status of the command." (by @Barmar), this explanation is excellently clear and easy to understand, but speak doesn't precise enough for programmers, I want to see the reference of this point from authorities such as TLDP or GNU man page, please help me find it out, thanks again!

Comment: TLDP is *not* an authoritative source -- the ABS is outright infamous for showcasing bad practices in bash, much as w3schools is in the JavaScript world.

Comment: Related:  [How is the return status of a variable assignment determined?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/270828/80216)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Upon executing a command as `$(command)` allows the [output of the command to replace itself](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution).

When you say:

```
a=$(false)             # false fails; the output of false is stored in the variable a
```

the output produced by the command `false` is stored in the variable `a`.  Moreover, the exit code is the same as produced by the command.  `help false` would tell:

```
false: false
    Return an unsuccessful result.
    
    Exit Status:
    Always fails.
```

On the other hand, saying:

```
$ false                # Exit code: 1
$ a=""                 # Exit code: 0
$ echo $?              # Prints 0
```

causes the exit code for the assignment to `a` to be returned which is `0`.

---

EDIT:

Quoting from the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion):

> If one of the expansions contained a command substitution, the exit
> status of the command is the exit status of the last command
> substitution performed.

Quoting from [BASHFAQ/002](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002):

> **How can I store the return value and/or output of a command in a
> variable?**
>
> ...
>
> `output=$(command)`
>
> `status=$?`
>
> The assignment to `output` has no effect on `command`'s exit status, which
> is still in `$?`.

This is not bash-specific. Quoting the end of section  2.9.1 "Simple Commands" in the "Shell & Utilities" volume of the The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, POSIX.1-2017 :

> If there is no command name, but the command contained a command substitution, the command shall complete with the exit status of the last command substitution performed

Comment: Keep in mind that this doesn't apply to `local` variables (eg, `local output=$(command)`), because `local` is a command itself and its exit-code will overwrite that of the assigned function.

Comment: @sevko this distinction makes all the difference, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Regarding @sevko & @qodeninja 's comments about `local`s, this can easily be circumvented by initialization after declaration unless the variable is also `readonly`: `local my_var; my_var=$(command); local status=$?`

Comment: My god, this wasted so much of my time. Thank you @sevko, I may have never figured this out on my own.

Comment: The pitfall of combining `local` declaration with command substitution is described in [Bash Pitfall #27](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#local_var.3D.24.28cmd.29). It also affects `declare` and `export`.

Comment: shellcheck catches and explains the `local` and `export` pitfalls. shellcheck saves lives, use it.

Answer (score 25):

Note that this isn't the case when combined with `local`, as in `local variable="$(command)"`. That form will exit successfully even if `command` failed.

Take this Bash script for example:

```
#!/bin/bash

function funWithLocalAndAssignmentTogether() {
    local output="$(echo "Doing some stuff.";exit 1)"
    local exitCode=$?
    echo "output: $output"
    echo "exitCode: $exitCode"
}

function funWithLocalAndAssignmentSeparate() {
    local output
    output="$(echo "Doing some stuff.";exit 1)"
    local exitCode=$?
    echo "output: $output"
    echo "exitCode: $exitCode"
}

funWithLocalAndAssignmentTogether
funWithLocalAndAssignmentSeparate
```

Here is the output of this:

```
nick.parry@nparry-laptop1:~$ ./tmp.sh 
output: Doing some stuff.
exitCode: 0
output: Doing some stuff.
exitCode: 1
```

This is because `local` is actually a builtin command, and a command like `local variable="$(command)"` calls `local` *after* substituting the output of `command`. So you get the exit status from `local`.

Comment: The reason is that `local` (likewise for `export`) is a bash builtin function, and the way it's invoked with the first example result in a success, thus a `0` exit code.

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I've edited this answer to clarify the situation; the issue only arises when you combine `local` with the assignment in a single statement. (Fun fact: because `local` is a builtin command, rather than special syntax, you can even write something like `local "$(echo foo=bar)"` and it will behave the same as `local foo=bar`, creating a local variable named `foo` and initializing it to `bar`. By contrast, the command `"$(echo foo=bar)"` will give you `bash: foo=bar: command not found`, because Bash isn't expecting an assignment at that point.)

Comment: Hah! This is exactly the detail that was tripping me up!

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same problem yesterday (Aug 29 2018).

In addition to `local` mentioned in [Nick P.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50494835/5001419) and @sevko's comment in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157997/5001419), `declare` in global scope also has the same behavior.

Here's my Bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash

func1()
{
    ls file_not_existed
    local local_ret1=$?
    echo "local_ret1=$local_ret1"

    local local_var2=$(ls file_not_existed)
    local local_ret2=$?
    echo "local_ret2=$local_ret2"

    local local_var3
    local_var3=$(ls file_not_existed)
    local local_ret3=$?
    echo "local_ret3=$local_ret3"
}

func1

ls file_not_existed
global_ret1=$?
echo "global_ret1=$global_ret1"

declare global_var2=$(ls file_not_existed)
global_ret2=$?
echo "global_ret2=$global_ret2"

declare global_var3
global_var3=$(ls file_not_existed)
global_ret3=$?
echo "global_ret3=$global_ret3"
```

The output:

```
$ ./declare_local_command_substitution.sh 2>/dev/null 
local_ret1=2
local_ret2=0
local_ret3=2
global_ret1=2
global_ret2=0
global_ret3=2
```

Note the values of `local_ret2` and `global_ret2` in the output above. The exit codes are overwritten by `local` and `declare`.

My Bash version:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION 
4.4.19(1)-release
```

Answer (score 4):

(not an answer to original question but too long for comment)

Note that `export A=$(false); echo $?` outputs 0!  Apparently the rules quoted in [devnull's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157997/239657) no longer apply.  To add a bit of context to that quote (emphasis mine):

> 3.7.1 Simple Command Expansion
>
> ...
>
> If there is a command name left after expansion, execution proceeds as described *below*. **Otherwise**, the command exits. If one of the expansions contained a command substitution, the exit status of the command is the exit status of the last command substitution performed. If there were no command substitutions, the command exits with a status of zero.
>
> 3.7.2 Command Search and Execution [ — *this is the "below" case*]

IIUC the manual describes `var=foo` as *syntactic* special case of `var=foo command...` (pretty confusing, semantically they are very different!).  The "exit status of the last command substitution" rule only applies to the no-command case.

While it's tempting to think of `export var=foo` as a "modified assignment syntax", it isn't — `export` is a builtin command (that just happens to take assignment-like args).

=> If you want to export a var AND capture command substitution status, do it in 2 stages:

```
A=$(false)
# ... check $?
export A
```

This way also works in `set -e` mode — exits immediately if the command substitution return non-0.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the exit code of the command substitution is the exit code of the substituted command, so

```
FOO=$(false)
echo $?
---
1
```

However, unexpectedly, adding `export` to the beginning of that produces a different result:

```
export FOO=$(false)
echo $?
---
0
```

This is because, while the substituted command `false` fails, the `export` command succeeds, and that is the exit code returned by the statement.