# How to check the exit status using an 'if' statement

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, error-handling, exit-code

What would be the best way to check the *exit status* in an `if` statement in order to echo a specific output?

I'm thinking of it being:

```sh
if [ $? -eq 1 ] 
then
    echo "blah blah blah"
fi
```

The issue I am also having is that the `exit` statement is before the `if` statement simply because it has to have that exit code. Also, I know I'm doing something wrong since the exit would obviously exit the program.

Comment: Plaese post your complete script (or at least a broader scope). Else this seems fine.

Comment: If you need to use the exit code from some particular program invocation in two different places, then you need to preserve it - something along the lines of `some_program; rc=$?; if [ ${rc} -eq 1 ] .... fi ; exit ${rc}`

Answer (score 562):

*Every* command that runs has an exit status.

That check is looking at the exit status of the command that finished most recently before that line runs.

If you want *your* script to exit when that test returns true (the previous command failed) then you put `exit 1` (or whatever) inside that `if` block after the `echo`.

That being said, if you are running the command and are wanting to test its output, using the following is often more straightforward.

```
if some_command; then
    echo command returned true
else
    echo command returned some error
fi
```

Or to turn that around use `!` for negation

```
if ! some_command; then
    echo command returned some error
else
    echo command returned true
fi
```

Note though that neither of those cares *what* the error code is. If you know you only care about a specific error code then you need to check `$?` manually.

Comment: @deadcell4 When one needs to terminate a shell script on a program failure, the following idiom is useful `a_command || return 1`

Comment: @gboffi `return` only works in a function and a sourced script. You need `exit` for the other case (which does too much in a function and a sourced script). But yes, that's certainly a reasonable pattern if you don't need any specific cleanup or extra output.

Comment: I have to say that `dash`, the default non-interactive shell in many modern linux distributions, don't care of the distinction between `return` and `exit` inside of executed shell scripts. `dash` exits the script even if I use `return` in it.

Comment: What is the logic behind the last two checks? It seems counter-intuitive that the condition `if <command>` passes if the exit code is 0. In any other language it would be the other way around

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE:  This won't work for pipes.  `if ! some_command | some_other_command` will ignore the status of some_command.  The two most command workarounds are to `set -o pipefail` (may change functionality in other parts of your program) or to move the `if` statement to `if [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 ]]` as a separate follow-up command (ugly, but functional).  If you're using `set -e` then you'll also want to add `|| true` to the end of the pipe when using the second solution since removing the pipe from the control flow offered by `if` would otherwise cause it to immediately exit.

Comment: What about `grep`; which has 3 possible exit codes: 0 - something was selected, 1 - nothing; 2 - an error.

Comment: Is there a way to fetch the error code in the "then" branch above, I know it returned non-zero but can I get exactly what flavor of non-zero?

Comment: "true" in this context means 0, as opposed to most other languages. It is hard to find information about the bash if statement since most guides actually describe the test command.

Comment: _The test-commands list is executed, and if its return status is zero, the consequent-commands list is executed._ (from [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs)). The logic behind this is simple. Shell commands return error codes, not data values. For readability, the `if` body (the consequent-commands list) is executed if the command succeeds, i.e., it returns no error, i.e. 0.

Answer (score 425):

Note that exit codes != 0 are used to report errors. So, it's better to do:

```
retVal=$?
if [ $retVal -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error"
fi
exit $retVal
```

instead of

```
# will fail for error codes == 1
retVal=$?
if [ $retVal -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "Error"
fi
exit $retVal
```

Comment: You must test on retVal, because $? after the assignment of retVal is not the return value from your command.

Comment: Not really: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002 - however, I agree that edit improves the readability.

Comment: Just found this post that explains it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157938/bash-exit-code-of-variable-assignment-to-command-substitution

Comment: [`dnf check-update`](https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#check-update-command-label) returns 0 (no updates), 100 (updates available) or 1 (error).

Comment: @jww - well, that's not quite a good idea to go against convention (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html). But, well, there is nothing to prevent that. If `dnf` developers have chosen this way, it's their choice. But still, their choice doesn't make the specification to be broken :)

Comment: `# will fail for error codes > 1` but `$retVal -eq 1` checks for error code equal 1?

Comment: @Timo - true, true; This is a perfect sample of why shouldn't you trust comments - they become outdated at some point. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: Why not simpilfy the if statement to `if [ $? -ne 0 ];`

Comment: @carlin.scott - Follow your heart, follow your soul, I am not here to tell you how things must be done :)

Comment: @carlin.scott because you only get one chance to capture `$?`, and we need to use it twice -- once in the `if`, and once in the `return`.

Answer (score 99):

An alternative to an explicit `if` statement

Minimally:

`test $? -eq 0 || echo "something bad happened"`

Complete:

```
EXITCODE=$?
test $EXITCODE -eq 0 && echo "something good happened" || echo "something bad happened";
exit $EXITCODE
```

Answer (score 67):

`$?` is a parameter like any other. You can save its value to use before ultimately calling `exit`.

```
exit_status=$?
if [ $exit_status -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "blah blah blah"
fi
exit $exit_status
```

Answer (score 55):

For the record, if the script is run with `set -e` (or `#!/bin/bash -e`) and you therefore cannot check `$?` directly (since the script would terminate on any return code other than zero), but want to handle a specific code, [@gboffis comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675681/how-to-check-the-exit-status-using-an-if-statement#comment41950943_26675771) is great:

```bash
/some/command || error_code=$?
if [ "${error_code}" -eq 2 ]; then
   ...
```

Comment: Doesn't this break if `/some/command` is in the PATH? `error_code` is not set.

Comment: I don't see how that would interfere. You can try `/bin/mkdir` on an existing directory, that should return 1. Are you certain the command you tried did return an exit code other than 0? `/usr/bin/file` on an non-existant file for example prints an error but still returns 0 

Comment: @Justin, I agree. I think it's better to use `|| is_fail=true; if [ "$is_fail" = true ]; then . . . `

Comment: `error_code` will only be set if `/some/command` returns with non-zero status.

Answer (score 37):

Just to add to the helpful and detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26675771/6862601):

If you have to check the exit code explicitly, it is better to use the arithmetic operator, `(( ... ))`, this way:

```
run_some_command
(($? != 0)) && { printf '%s\n' "Command exited with non-zero"; exit 1; }
```

Or, use a `case` statement:

```
run_some_command; ec=$?  # grab the exit code into a variable so that it can
                         # be reused later, without the fear of being overwritten
case $ec in
    0) ;;
    1) printf '%s\n' "Command exited with non-zero"; exit 1;;
    *) do_something_else;;
esac
```

---

Related answer about error handling in Bash:

- [Raise error in a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265513/6862601)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why _it is better to use the arithmetic operator_?

Comment: This answer is actually incorrect. You can't use `$?` in a boolean check like that, regardless of whether you use `(( $? != 0 ))` or `[[ $? -ne 0 ]]` because it doesn't get parsed like normal vars do ([related description](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-brackets.html#:~:text=However%20if%20you%20set%20a%20variable%20to%20the%20results%20of%20an%20arithmetic%20expression%20that%20will%20be%20set%20to%20the%20more%20logical%20True%20(1)%20/%20False%20(0))).

Comment: Re why arithmetic is better: It's not, just personal preference. I like it more b/c it's shorter, i.e. `(( $retVal )) && echo 'ERROR'` instead of `(( $retVal != 0 ))` or `[[ $retVal -ne 0 ]]` but that doesn't necessarily mean it's _better_. In fact, the shortcut I like to use would be confusing to anyone who doesn't know Bash all that well.

Answer (score 18):

If you are writing a function – which is always preferred – you can *propagate* the error like this:

```
function()
{
    if <command>; then
        echo worked
    else
        return
    fi
}
```

Now, the caller can do things like `function && next` as expected! This is useful if you have a lot of things to do in the `if` block, etc. (otherwise there are one-liners for this). It can easily be tested using the `false` command.

Answer (score 16):

you can just add this if statement:

```
if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
    echo 'The previous command was not executed successfully';
fi
```

Answer (score 12):

Using [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`) you can simply use:

```
if [[ $(false)? -eq 1 ]]; then echo "yes" ;fi
```

When using Bash and `set -e` is on, you can use:

```
false || exit_code=$?
if [[ ${exit_code} -ne 0 ]]; then echo ${exit_code}; fi
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm missing the most simple solution, which is just to use the `&&` operator:

```
command --with parameters && echo "Command completed succesfully"
```

-- assuming `command` returns 0 on success, and non-zero on failure as Bash expects (which is kind of the opposite of many programming languages!)

The `||` operator can be used for failure:

```
commamnd --with parameters || echo "Command failed"
```

Answer (score 2):

This might only be useful in a limited set of use-cases, I use this specifically when I need to capture the output from a command and write it to a log file if the exit code reports that something went wrong.

```
RESULT=$(my_command_that_might_fail)
if (exit $?) 
then
    echo "everything went fine."    
else
    echo "ERROR: $RESULT" >> my_logfile.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Below test scripts below work for

- simple bash test commands
- multiple test commands
- bash test commands with pipe included:

```bash
if [[ $(echo -en "abc\n def" |grep -e "^abc") && ! $(echo -en "abc\n def" |grep -e "^def") ]] ; then
  echo "pipe true"
else
  echo "pipe false"
fi
if [[ $(echo -en "abc\n def" |grep -e "^abc") && $(echo -en "abc\n def" |grep -e "^def") ]] ; then
  echo "pipe true"
else
  echo "pipe false"
fi
```

The output is:

```
pipe true
pipe false
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution handling `set -euo pipefail` gracefully:

```
# ...

some-command && true
SOME_COMMAND_EXIT_STATUS="$?"

# ...
```

### Example

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

# due to "set -e", using " ... && true" construct to avoid script from
# exiting immediately on expectable nonzero exit code.
# As per the Bash Reference Manual:
#
#   "[...] The shell does not exit if the command that fails is
#    [...] part of any command executed in a && or || list
#    [as long as it isn't the final command in this list]"
#
# see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html
# see "-e" at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html

some-command && true
SOME_COMMAND_EXIT_STATUS="$?"

if [[ "$SOME_COMMAND_EXIT_STATUS" == 4 ]]; then
  echo "some-command exit status was 4"
else
  echo "some-command exit status was unequal 4"
fi
```