# Bash conditional based on exit code of command

Tags: bash, shell, process, command, exit-code

In Bash, I would like an if statement which is based of the exit code of running a command. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ./success.sh ]; then
    echo "First: success!"
else
    echo "First: failure!"
fi

if [ ./failure.sh ]; then
    echo "Second: success!"
else
    echo "Second: failure!"
fi
```

**success.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

exit 0
```

**failure.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

exit 1
```

This should print out:

```
First: success!
Second: failure!
```

How would I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: You should remove the *signals* tag from your post. There is no such thing like an *exit **signal***, and your post is about *exit **codes***, not signals. Asking with which signal a program was terminated, would also be a meaningful question, but this is not what you have asked.

Comment: See this: [How to check the exit status using an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675681).

Comment: Relevant: https://shapeshed.com/unix-exit-codes/

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Just remove the brackets:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ./success.sh; then
    echo "First: success!"
else
    echo "First: failure!"
fi

if ./failure.sh; then
    echo "Second: success!"
else
    echo "Second: failure!"
fi
```

Explanation: the thing that goes between `if` and `then` is a command (or series of commands), the exit status of which is used to determine whether to run the `then` clause, or the `else` clause. This is exactly what you want.

So why do people use brackets in `if` statements? It's because normally you want to decide which branch of the `if` to run based on some conditional expression (is `"$a"` equal to `"$b"`, does a certain file exist, etc). `[` is actually a command which parses its arguments as a conditional expression (ignoring the final `]`), and then exits with either success or failure depending on whether the conditional is true or false. Essentially, `[ ]` functions as an adapter that lets you use conditional expressions instead of command success/failure in your `if` statements. In your case, you *want* success/failure not a conditional expression, so don't use the adapter.

BTW, you'll also sometimes see `if [[ some expression ]]; then` and `if (( some expression )); then`. `[[ ]]` and `(( ))` are conditional expressions built into bash syntax (unlike `[`, which is a command). `[[ ]]` is essentially a better version of `[ ]` (with some syntax oddities cleaned up and some features added), and `(( ))` is a somewhat similar construct that does arithmetic expressions.

BTW2 another thing you'll see in scripts is the exit status being tested by checking the special parameter `$?`, which gives the exit status of the last command. It looks like this:

```
somecommand
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Somecommand: success!"
else
    echo "Somecommand: failure!"
fi
```

I really consider this cargo cult programming. People are used to seeing `[ ]` conditional expressions in `if` statements, and this idiom puts the success test in the form of a conditional expression. But let me run through how it works: it takes the exit status of the command, puts it in a conditional expression, has `[ ]` evaluate that *and turn it right back into an exit status* so `if` can use it. That whole rigamarole is unnecessary; just put the command directly in the `if` statement.

Comment: Note that there is something a bit weird in the way bash `if` works. An exit code of zero causes bash to take the `if` branch, and a non-zero exit code causes bash to take the `else` branch. That's backwards from other languages, where zero is 'falsy' and non-zero is 'truthy'. http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: @ChristianLong Yep, it's confusing all right. The shell convention works this way because an exit code of 0 indicates that the command succeeded, and success is 'truthy', so (in exit code context) 0 has to be 'truthy' (and nonzero indicates failure, so has to be 'falsy'). IMO it's easiest to think in terms of command success vs failure instead of zero vs nonzero; that's another advantage of putting the command directly in the `if` statement.

Comment: What do you do if the command includes flags? For instance, how do I get this to work `((git diff --quiet == 1)) && echo yes || echo no`?

Comment: @ricab What's the `== 1` supposed to mean? If you're trying to test the command's success/failure, just include the flags as usual: `if git diff --quiet; then echo yes; else echo no; fi`

Comment: The `== 1` stands for a check for a specific error code; the example isn't important. I am essentially after the syntax to have a command with flags in one of the sides of a comparison within `(( ))`.

Comment: If it helps, `git diff --quiet` exits with 1 when there are differences (which I want to detect), even though the command succeeded. The `if` you suggest does not distinguish that from a failure.

Comment: @ricab If you want to detect specific error status(es), you do need to run the command first, then check `$?`, like `git diff --quiet; if (( $? == 1 ))` (and if you want to do multiple checks, store it in a variable first). See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62033740/bash-conditional-based-on-specific-exit-code-of-command/62033933#62033933).

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the case. It's awkward that you can inline some commands but not others, so I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the accepted answer, note that you sometimes may wish to preserve the exit status for later use. In such cases, you can save it into a variable and then test that variable.

Here is an example using your commands and the Bash arithmetic `(( ))` command for tests :

```
#!/bin/bash

./success.sh
es1=$?

echo "exit status = $es1"
if (( es1 == 0 )); then
    echo "First: success! (es1 = $es1)"
else
    echo "First: failure! (es1 = $es1)"
fi

./failure.sh
es2=$?

echo "exit status = $es2"
if (( es2 > 0 )); then
    echo "Second: failure! ($es2 is greater than 0)"
else
    echo "Second: success!"
fi
```

Comment: Note that when [*set shell option* `errexit`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#index-set) is on (e.g. with an explicit `set -e`, or when calling the script with `bash -e script.sh`,  executing the line with `./failure.sh` will immediately exit the `script.sh` script. This can be prevented with a `... && true` guard, e.g. `./failure.sh && true`.