# Conditional return with default return not working

Tags: bash

I have a bash function, whic role is to receive an array, loop thru the array and call another function `is_node` that check if an node element exist.

If a node element exists `is_node' returns 0, if trows an error returns a number between 1-6, otherwise returns 7 or above.

My issue with `is_nodes` is even if 'is_node' `return 0` will `return 7`

! return 7, should be triggered if no error appears and no nodes exists

```
 function is_nodes() { 
    local arr=("$@")    

    for node in ${arr}
    do
        is_node $node 
        if [[  $? -gt 0 && $? -lt 7  ]]
        then
            return 2
        elif [[ $? -eq 0 ]]
        then
            return 0
        fi  
    done
    # default
    return 7
}
```

pesudeo-code

```
is_nodes receive an array (node1 node2 node3)
loop
  is_node node1 triggers an error ?; no go further
  is_node node1 exists(return 0) ?; no continue   
  is_node node2 triggers an error ?; no go further
  is_node node2 exists(return 0) ?; yes get out of the function and return 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash conditional based on exit code of command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command)

Comment: `Expanding an array without an index only gives the first element.` (thanks [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)). Also you should definitely store your function return's code in a variable, there's no way the three `$?` correctly reference it.

Comment: @JulienLopez is about function $? checks and returns, is different

Comment: More specifically it will never return 0 because if `[[  $? -gt 0 && $? -lt 7  ]]` is true then it returns 2, if it's false it overwrites `$?` with its return code which will be 1 ; `test` / `[[` is a statement too and writes its return code to `$?`. Not sure whether the second `$?` of your first condition correctly refers to the return code of `is_node`.

Comment: seems my understanding of $? related to functions was not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt at fixing your code.

```
# Don't use Bash-only keyword function
is_nodes() {
    # New variable
    local rc
    # No array needed, just loop over arguments
    for node in "$@"
    do
        # Take care to properly quote argument
        is_node "$node"
        # Capture result
        rc=$?
        if [[ "$rc" -gt 0 && "$rc" -lt 7  ]]
        then
            return 2
        elif [[ "$rc" -eq 0 ]]
        then
            return 0
        fi  
    done
    # default
    return 7
}
```

Part of me wants to refactor the `return 0` so you don't need to explicitly compare `$?` to zero.

```
        is_node "$node" && return 0
```

and then correspondingly take out the `elif` branch.  Then the condition in the `if` can also be reduced to just `if [[ "$rc" -lt 7 ]]`.

Comment: does 'rc' variable name has a meaning, or is random name ?

Comment: The variable name has no particular significance; you can call it `shirley` if you like.  I used it as an abbreviation of "result code" or "return code".

Comment: if I do is_node "$node" &&  is_valid=0 || is_valid=1 , I catch the wrong $?

Comment: Yeah, if you do `if ! success` or `success || something` then the result code of `success` will be lost.  The value of `$?` is always the result code of the *immediately* previous command.