# What is the function of * between double brackets?

Tags: bash

I would like to understand the function of * in the if statement as follow:

```
if [[ '/bin/somecommand 2>dev/null' ! = *'1'* ]];
```

is to examininate if the return value is return as 1, but if I leave it as

```
if [[ '/bin/somecommand 2>dev/null' ! = '1' ]];
```

it will not examinate proper value. I just try to understand what is the function of the * at the front and back of '1' does it make it a integer for comparison purpose?

I have tried the following combination

```
if [[ '/bin/somecommand 2>dev/null' ! = '1' ]];
if [[ '/bin/somecommand 2>dev/null' ! = 1 ]];
```

None of the way would return the right result other than the first one with * at the front and back of the '1'.

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Are you trying to check if `somecommand` returns 1, returns any error generally, or if it *prints* 1 to stdout?

Comment: I assume that instead of `'/bin/somecommand 2>dev/null'` it should correctly be `$(/bin/somecommand 2>dev/null)`.

Comment: Are you trying to test the *output* of `/bin/somecommand` (i.e. what it prints to standard output while it's running), or its *exit status* (a numeric code it "returns" when it exits, where normally 0 indicates that the command succeded, and something other than 0 indicates it failed)? The command you've given has several mistakes, so it's hard to tell what it's supposed to do.

Comment: It return value of 0 or 1 to confirm if certain module is installed.

Comment: If you are worried about the `return` then just `if /bin/somecommand 2>/dev/null; then ... ` (you don't use the `[[ ... ]]` if you are checking a command return, only if checking the output [e.g. the result of the *command substitution*].)

Comment: If it's the exit status you want to test, see: [Bash conditional based on exit code of command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you had backticks instead of single quotes for the command, and no space in `!=`:

```
[[ `/bin/somecommand 2>dev/null` != *'1'* ]]
```

In a double bracket `[[ .. ]]` expression, the right-hand side of `=`/`==` and `!=` is interpreted as a glob pattern, so `*` means "any string".

Essentially, `*'1'*` will match all string that contains a `1` anywhere (such as `foo1bar` and `3210`), while `'1'` will only match exactly the string `1`.