# Having a bash "while" loop either read line from STDIN, OR call function

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting.  I can do this:

```
while [ read line ] 
do
    # do something with $lin
done
```

I can also do this:

```
while [ checkBufferedLines ]
do
    # do something
done
```

But what I'm wanting to accomplish is something like this:

```
while [ read line ] || [ checkBufferedLines ]
do
    # do something with $line or the buffered lines
done
```

Concisely, I want the loop to run if a `$line` is assigned from `stdin` or if a function call returns `true` or `1`, *and* I would like a `$line` to short-circuit the function call if present.

That's what I'm trying to accomplish; can this be done? Or will `read line` stop the loop so the `checkBufferedLines` function isn't also evaluated on the 'or' condition?

Comment: The `read` call is blocking. The right side of the conditional will only be evaluated after read completes the stream and returns false.

Comment: `while [ read line ] ` will not work -- you use `[ ]` to evaluate a conditional expression (e.g. `[ 5 -lt 7 ]`), not to contain a command like `read`. See: [Bash conditional based on exit code of command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command/49850110).