# Bash function for zero length string or with whitespace

Tags: regex, bash, is-empty

In bash I can use `-z string` and `-n string` to see if the string length is zero or not.
Would like to write a bash function that returns true or false, not only if length is zero but also if it is all whitespace.  Or is there a way without needing a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression:

```
if [[ $string =~ ^" "*$ ]]
```

or you can remove all the spaces before testing with `-z`:

```
if [[ -z "${string// /}" ]]
```

Comment: Both are different as `[:space:]` encompasses a larger set of possible characters.

Comment: @kvantour If you want to include all spacey characters in the second form, use `[[ -z "${string//[[:space:]]/}" ]]`

Comment: I know, I just wasn't sure how to just match space in a bash regexp, because quoting a regexp makes it literal. @kvantour

Comment: @Barmar `[[ $string =~ ^" "*$ ]]`

Comment: If I make a function  `zblank` that returns either `1` or `0`, could I do the following:  `[[ zblank "$s" ]] && printf '%s\n' "Option not used"`.

Comment: Only the parts you actually quote are treated literally. `[[ $string =~ ^\ *$ ]]` or `[[ $string %" "*$ ]]` would work. That said, a common workaround is to store the regex in a variable, then use an unquoted parameter expansion, like `regex="^ *$"; [[ $string =~ $regex ]]`.

Comment: @Angio With a function, you wouldn't use `[[ ]]` -- those allow you to use a conditional expression in place of a command, but a function is already a command. So just use `zblank "$s" && printf '%s\n' "Option not used"`. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command/49850110#49850110) has more explanation of a similar situation.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Actually  `[[ zblank "$s" ]]` did not work but `[[ $(lg "$s") ]]` did work.  Will check out your way.

Comment: @GordonDavisson To do the negation of the function command, how would I go with your strategy?

Comment: @Angio `[[ $(lg "$s") ]]` is testing whether `lg` prints anything, not checking its exit status. Is your function printing something, or `return`ing a status? Oh, and to negate it you'd use either `! zblank "$s" && printf ...` or `zblank "$s" || printf ...`

Comment: Its purpose is more intended to be a status value.

Comment: @Angio In that case, there's something wrong with how the function's written. Try `zblank() { if [[ $string =~ ^" "*$ ]]; then return 0; else return 1; fi; }` or even simpler just `zblank() { [[ $1 =~ ^" "*$ ]]; }` (since functions implicitly return the status of the last command in them).

Comment: That's what I've done. Using `zblank "$src" && printf '%s\n' "src used"` is still valid, am I correct?

Comment: You don't quote `$string` when using regular expressions?

Comment: @Angio It's not necesssary to quote variables inside `[[ ]]`, because there's no word splitting in that context.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be portable to non-bash shells (e.g. dash, which is the default /bin/sh on some Linux distros), you can use this:

```
if [ "$variable" = "${variable#*[![:space:]]}" ]; then
```

Explanation: `${variable%pattern}` will remove a match of the pattern from the beginning of the variable's value *if* there is such a match. The pattern `*[![:space:]]` will match from the beginning of the string through the first non-space character (*if* there are any non-space characters in the string). Therefore, if there's at least one non-space character, the pattern will match and the variable's value will change, so the `=` test will fail. On the other hand if the string doesn't contain any non-space characters, the pattern won't match, the variable won't be modified, and the `=` test will succeed.

For completeness, you can also use `case` for this:

```
case "$variable" in
    *[![:space:]]* ) echo "variable is NOT empty" ;;
    * ) echo "variable IS empty" ;;
esac
```

Either of these should work in any POSIX-compliant shell.

Comment: I did not know you could use character classes in a glob

Comment: @kvantour Yep, according to [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_01) bracket expressions in a glob are almost identical to in a  regex. The only difference is you use `!` instead of `^` to negate the expression.

Answer (score -1):

Use the exit status of `grep -Pq '\S'`, which is `true` if there is at least 1 non-whitespace character, and `false` otherwise:

```
grep -Pq '\S' <<< " " && echo "not all whitespace" || echo "all whitespace"
# all whitespace

grep -Pq '\S' <<< "" && echo "not all whitespace" || echo "all whitespace" 
# all whitespace

grep -Pq '\S' <<< "a" && echo "not all whitespace" || echo "all whitespace"
# not all whitespace
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-q` : Quiet; do not write anything to standard output. Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found.

`\S` : non-whitespace character.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)