# Correct Formatting of Multiple Condition Bash IF Statement

Tags: bash, unix, curl, wget

I am trying to use an IF statement to:

1. Check if a server is UP
2. Check if a file exists on the server

**My Code So Far**

```
hostname="somehost.com"
file="somefile.txt"
URL="https://${hostname}/some/directory/${file}"
if [ "ping -c 1 -W 1 ${hostname} 2>/dev/null" ] & [ "wget --spider ${URL} 2>/dev/null" ];
then
echo -e "${hostname} is UP and ${file} is AVAILABLE"
else
echo -e "${hostname} is DOWN or ${file} is UNAVAILABLE"
fi
```

I have tried testing the IF statement by entering an incorrect hostname and an incorrect file but, the result is incorrect.

**Current Output**

```
somehost.com is UP and somefile.txt is AVAILABLE
```

**Expected Output**

```
somehost.com is DOWN and somefile.txt is DOWN
```

Comment: Remove both the square brackets (those're for testing *expressions*, not commands; see ["Bash conditional based on exit code of command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command/49850110)) and the double-quotes around the commands (those make them plain strings rather than commands). Also, don't use `echo -e` -- the `-e` is just a compatibility trap waiting to cause trouble.

Comment: And use `&&` to make AND of both checks

Comment: Thanks everyone! Neither of those suggestions are producing the expected output unfortunately

Comment: @arnpry Please update your question with the current code.

Comment: @arnpry, if you don't show us _how_ you followed the instructions, we can't say why following them didn't fix things.

Comment: @arnpry, ...btw, as a rule, it's always a good habit to run code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fix what it identifies before asking questions here. I'd suggest doing that after updating your code per the two linked questions' answers, before editing or reposting this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expression1 && expression2
```

True if both expression1 **and** expression2 are true.

```
expression1 || expression2
```

True if either expression1 **or** expression2 is true.

The && and || operators do not evaluate expression2 if the value of expression1 is sufficient to determine the return value of the entire conditional expression.

From: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Compound-Commands