# IP address in condition statement bash profile

Tags: linux, bash

below ism y code

```
if [ ip add show tun0 2>/dev/null ] ; then
    export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:2123"
fi
```

But when i do echo after conencting

```
echo $http_proxy
```

it is not displaying. can advice?

Comment: First: when troubleshooting, remove the `2>/dev/null` so you can see the error message. Second: if the goal is to test the success/failure of `ip ...` as a command, remove the `[ ]` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command)).

Comment: You are not executing the command `ip`, you are executing the command `[`. The first word after the `if` is the command to be executed for testing the condition. This is described in the section _Compound Commands_ in the bash man-page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GordonDavisson suggested:

```
if ip add show tun0 2>/dev/null
then
   export http_proxy='http://127.0.0.1:2123'
fi
```

but you could also write it like this:

```
ip add show tun0 2>/dev/null && export http_proxy='http://127.0.0.1:2123'
```

`ip` will print stuff on stdout when successful, so maybe you want to do `>& /dev/null`?  Instead of throwing all the data away, consider storing it in a variable, then you can always add a verbose flag to your program at some later point to print the content of that variable if you need to debug it.

Comment: i tried but it not showing. i connect vpn it use tun0. when i echo it not showing the value

Comment: What is not showing?  If you get no output, then it would mean that you don't have the tun0 interface.  Or you have a different error, so run the program without the 2>/dev/null redirect and tell us what you get.

Comment: was my mistake, i need to relog in to shell. thank you guys for the great help

Comment: Where do you display the var? Outside the script that adds the interface? If yes, then the outer bash ignores the definition of the scrip (sub-shell).