# Bash check return code of a command inline

Tags: bash, return

Ok, so this is killing me, it might sound like a simple question, but I cannot get it to work
Im trying to check a command return code without storing it on a variable and simple cant.

```
[ $(true) ] && echo Worked
[[ $(true) ]] && echo Worked

[ $(true) -eq 0 ] && echo Worked
[[ $(true) -eq 0 ]] && echo Worked

[ "$(true)" -eq "0" ] && echo Worked
[[ "$(true)" -eq "0" ]] && echo Worked

[ $(true) -eq '0' ] && echo Worked
[[ $(true) -eq '0' ]] && echo Worked
```

Well, I tried pretty much every single combination, with quotes on one side, both sides, the left side, the right side...
Some of them will actually output Worked but they are not actually checking the return code, if you test them with false they will also "Worked"

My final code is to run 5 commands and get the first that works, and the idea is to put them on a if/elseif statement, but I really don't want to put every single command on a  variable and then check the variable, its annoying.

Comment: `true && echo worked` gives `worked`, `false && echo worked` gives no echo ...

Comment: You're confusing the *output* of a command (i.e. what it prints) with its *exit status* (i.e. whether it succeeds or fails). `$( )` gets its output, not its exit status. `[ ]` and `[[ ]]` do tests on strings and numbers, not exit statuses. Things like `if` and `&&` and `||` test exit statuses directly, so just use `command && echo Worked`. See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command/49850110#49850110).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you very much for that, Never crossed my mind to test without bracket but your explanation clarify everything, if you want, post it as answer !!!

Comment: @Claudio you are absolutely right as well, appreciate your help !!!

Comment: Are you looking for: `cmd1 || cmd2 || cmd3 || cmd4 || cmd5 && echo 'one command succeeded'`? This tries each command until one succeeds. If a command succeeds, no further commands in the OR list are executed (it skips to echo). If none succeed, echo doesn't execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The single bracket `[` or double one `[[` are not needed to check a commands return code.**

Yes the single one `[` is for checking numeric or string values with special operators:

```bash
[ 1 -eq 1 ] && echo worked
worked

[ "1" -eq "1" ] && echo worked
worked

[ 1 -eq 2 ] && echo worked # nothing

[ "1" -eq "2" ] && echo worked # nothing
```

And the double is the same but with different operators  :

```bash
[[ 1 == 1 ]] && echo worked
worked

[[ "1" == "1" ]] && echo worked
worked

[[ 1 == 2 ]] && echo worked # nothing

[[ "1" == "2" ]] && echo worked # nothing
```

But for checking a command return value we do not need to wrap the command inside single or double brackets

```bash
# file.txt exists 
ls file.txt  > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo worked
worded

# file.json does not exist
ls file.json > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo worked # nothing
```

It is true for `if / else` statement

```bash
# not needed
# if [ ls file.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 ]; then

# or
# if [[ ls file.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 ]]; then


if ls file.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo found
else
    echo file not found
fi
```

---

NOTE
For not making it complicated I did not mention all the differences between single bracket `[` and double one `[[`
Please refer to [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for more information
And thanks 
[Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) for commenting and reminding me this.

Comment: This explanation of the difference between `[ ]` and `[[ ]]` isn't quite right. They do have some different operators, but both use `-eq` for *numeric* comparison, and `=` for *string* comparison (e.g. `[ 1 -eq 01 ]` evaluates as true, and `[ 1 = 01 ]` as false). Bash accepts `==` as a synonym for `=` in both, but not all other shells do (and if you're specifically using bash, `[[ ]]` has much cleaner syntax so you should just use that). See [BashFAQ #31: "What is the difference between `test`, `[` and `[[` ?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)

Comment: @GordonDavisson thanks for the comment, yes you are right and I knew there are other differences, but did not want to make it complicated for him. I will update the answer, adding a **note** about what you mentioned, and please feel free to modify the answer. I appreciate if a senior one helps me learning bash correctly.