# File1: Binary operator expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to create a shell script as below on Linux.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ cp file1 /tmp ];
then
  rm file1
fi
```

But I am getting an error message as "**file1:binary operator required**"
I have tried a lot of options like enclosing line 2 within [[ ]], () etc but it's not working. I am not sure what am I missing. I even tried searching for other similar questions on StackOverflow but none are solving my problem.

So can you please help?

Comment: Don't put `cp file1 /tmp` inside `[]`.

Comment: Why did you think you needed `[` at all? That's used for evaluating conditional expressions like `$variable = "string"`

Comment: I am new to shell scripting. I read that we need to enclose the condition after if in [ ]. Hence I did it

Comment: `cp file1 /tmp` is not a condition, it's a command.

Comment: See ["Bash conditional based on exit code of command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command/49850110).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write:

```
#!/bin/bash
if cp file1 /tmp ; then
  rm file1
fi
```

Or

```
cp file1 /tmp && rm file1
```

Or perhaps directly:

```
mv file1 /tmp
```

Comment: This is an exercise given to use if condition so the 1st one worked.Thanks