# How to make a variable larger by 1

Tags: bash, loops, syntax, integer, increment

I am trying to write a bash script that essentially acts like the traceroute command,
I have written the following code:

```
#! /bin/bash

ttl=1
dest_ip=$1

#Send packets with increasing ttl and stop when the ping is sucsessfull
until ["ping -t $ttl -c 1 $dest_ip" = "0"]; do
        echo "$ttl"
        (($ttl+=1))
done
```

I ran this and get the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WGZC.png)

Comment: Your condition also has syntax errors. Should just be `if <command>`. Your don't need `[` and whitespace is important to syntax.

Comment: First step when debugging a shell script: Paste it into shellcheck.net. Second step, run it with `bash -x`. Last resort: Post to [so].

Comment: @jordanm `until` is correct (it's a negated form of `while`). But the square-brackets do need to be removed, see ["Bash conditional based on exit code of command"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command).

Comment: Please always copy&paste error messages *as text* and format these in the same way as your code. [Edit] your question to fix this.

Comment: Set integer flag: `declare -i ttl=1; ttl+=1; echo $ttl`

Comment: `ttl` has the value 1. Therefore, parameter expansion replaces $ttl by 1. Therefore, the command `(($ttl+=1))` expands to `((1+=1))`, which obviously does not make sense. You can find this kind of error easily by debugging the program with `set -x` and/or using [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing the *`make a variable larger by 1`* issue ...

The error message shows that `(($tt1+=1)` is being processed as `((1+=1))` (ie, the `$tt1` is replaced by the value in `tt1`) which is generating the error message (`attempted assignment to non-variable`, ie, `1` is not a variable).

You want to reference the variable by name and not by value so: `((tt1+=1))`; alternatives: `((tt1++))` and `((tt1=tt1+1))`

Answer (score 1):

```
while !(ping -q -t $ttl -c 1 $dest_ip > output); do
    echo "$ttl"
    ttl=$((ttl+1))
```

done

Comment: The `()` just tells the shell to run the command in a subshell and is not necessary for this example.