# using return code of grep as true false in a complex bash if statement

Tags: bash, logical-operators

I want to have an if statement in bash that says

```
if ((var1 greater than var2) and 
   whole word var3 cannot be found in file path var4); then

    do this

fi
```

but I cannot seem to get the correct syntax

`if [[ "$VAR1" -gt "$VAR2" && ! grep -q -w "$VAR3" "$VAR4" ]] ; then`

I have tried many different combinations with `[]` `()` and still never works, anyone know of this?

is there a link to the bash boolean operation I can read up?

I have tried simpler expressions like `if [[ ! grep -q -w "$VAR3" "$VAR4" ]]; then` that had worked, but can't get it into a chain

Comment: are you sure you got `if [[ ! grep -q -w "$VAR3" "$VAR4" ]]; then` to work?

Comment: Don't use `[[ ]]` around commands; `[[ ]]` and `[ ]` are things that let you use test expressions (e.g. comparisons) *in places where you'd normally be testing a command's success*. That means you don't put them around a command you want to test the success of, like the `grep` command here. You should only put them around the test expression part. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957/bash-conditional-based-on-exit-code-of-command).

Comment: Re: "is there a link to the bash boolean operation I can read up?": The [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) is very helpful, though in your case the problem was that you already had some sort of misconception that led you to think the `grep` should be inside `[[ ... ]]`, and the reference manual does *not* make a point of addressing misconceptions, so you might have found it difficult to correct your misconception just by reading it. :-/

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) can identify many common problems with shell code.  The report includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: @pjh apparently shellcheck did not pick that up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
if ((VAR1 > VAR2)) && ! grep -q -w "$VAR3" "$VAR4"; then
    [...]
```

The `(( ))` operators are bash arithmetic.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression

**You can't use `grep` inside bash test `[[  ]]`**

Comment: Thanks, putting grep outside [[ ]] was the correct way to do it

Answer (score 1):

One idea:

```
if [[ "$VAR1" -gt "$VAR2" ]] && ! grep -q -w "$VAR3" "$VAR4" ; then
                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

Where:

- pull the `&& ! grep` outside of the `[[ ... ]]` construct

Comment: `grep -q -v ...` returns success if there's *even one* line that doesn't include the search term; whereas the OP only wants success if *no* lines include the search term. So the OP should stick with `! grep -q ...`.

Comment: @ruakh true; I was focused on a small sample in my env; thanks

Comment: Thanks, putting grep outside [[ ]] was the correct way to do it