# Why does `if [false]` evaluate to true but `if false` doesn't in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, boolean, sh

Running this script in bash will print "hello"

```
if [ false ]; then
    echo hello
fi
```

Running this script in bash will print "hello"

```
if [[ false ]]; then
    echo hello
fi
```

Only when I take away the brackets, bash will not print "hello"

```
if false; then
    echo hello
fi
```

I thought the entire premise of the brackets was to enable additional functionality like `&&` and `||`, why is it being counter-productive in this case?

edit:
is this what you mean by bash quoting? still prints "hello"

```
test=false
if [[ "$test" ]]; then
    echo hello
fi
```

Comment: `if false; then ... fi` runs the command `false(1)`, which always returns failure. `if [ false ]; then ... fi` runs the command `test(1)` (or a built in equivalent), which returns success because the string "false" is not empty.

Comment: "I thought the entire premise of the brackets was to enable additional functionality like `&&` and `||`" is entirely wrong; the semantics inside a `[ ]` or `[[ ]]` test is *completely different* from without them. For example, `ls -le foo` will run the `ls` command with the `l` and `s` options and the argument `foo`. But `[[ ls -le foo ]]` will try to convert `ls` and `foo` into integers (probably by resolving them as variables), and test whether `ls` is less than or equal to (the `-le` operator) `foo`. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849957).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if function_or_program; then
    # do something
fi
```

This checks if `function_or_program` exits with `0` and if it does, executes the `do something` block.

- `true` and `false` are functions (and programs) that exit with `0` and `1` respectively.
- `[` is a function (and a program, linked to `test`) that can be used to test strings and numbers.
- `[[` is a function that is similar to `[` but is more robust.

So, what you observed is that when using `[` and `[[` you are testing the *strings* `true` and `false`. All strings that do not have the length `0` are considered true so both `true` and `false` will be seen as `true`.

> I thought the entire premise of the brackets was to enable additional functionality like `&&` and `||`,

You can execute multiple programs/functions too:

```bash
if false || true; then
    # do something
fi
```

... and combining executing programs/functions with testing strings is also possible:

```bash
if ( false || true ) && [[ "$foo" == "$bar" ]]; then
    # do something
fi
```

Comment: @glennjackman Oh, thanks. I _am_ historic :-) I updated it.