# Check if remote directory exists using ssh

Tags: ssh

I am trying to find out it a remote directory exists or not. However I just cannot manage to do it.

So far I tried the following

```
if [ ssh myUser@myHost '[ -d /home/targetDirectory ]' ] ; then
    echo "Directory does exist"
fi
```

But I keep getting the error *ssh binary operator expected*.
I dont see what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: `[` is a command, not part of the syntax of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it, nearly.
Remove the outer brackets

```
if ssh myUser@myHost '[ -d /home/targetDirectory ]' ; then
    echo "Directory does exist"
fi
```

Comment: but why do I need to remove the outer brackets? I mean, how does bash interprets it with and without?

Comment: In the comment from @chepner is the key point, also look at [How to check the exit status using an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26675771/463115)

Comment: Ok, maybe I have to put some more time in understanding this, so far it is still confusing