# Using function exit status for conditional branching

Tags: bash, function

I have a bash function that returns an exit status.  How does one use the function taking arguments and returning an exit status, in an `if` construct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check the exit status using an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675681/how-to-check-the-exit-status-using-an-if-statement)

Comment: `if myfunction arg1 arg2; then echo success; else echo failure; fi` Alternatively, use `$?`, which is the exit code of the last command: `myfunction arg1 arg2; if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then echo success; else echo failure; fi`. Remember that new lines can be used in place of semicolon (`;`).

Comment: Does the function use `exit` or `return`?

Comment: It uses return 0 for success, whilst return 1 and greater for error.

Comment: Every command has an exit status, and arguments can be part of any simple command (whether it uses them or not).  What is it that you think is distinctive about the case you have in mind, that does not apply to all uses of an `if` construct?

Comment: Is `$?` the only way to get the exit status of a function?