# git run command if nothing to commit

Tags: bash, git

This question is probably about bash as much as it is about git.

How do I run a command if there is nothing to commit? I did the following, but it runs the `echo hello` command even if there is nothing to commit:

```sh
if git diff --exit-code; then
  echo hello
fi
```

Coming from a python background, what I assumed would happen is if `git ...` command is empty then the stuff inside the if statement would not execute. I have confirmed that `git diff --exit-code` returns nothing.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: Your current code echoes hello in the success case, not the failure case.

We can fix this by inverting the condition, so it becomes:

```sh
if ! git diff --exit-code; then
  echo hello
fi
```

I'd recommend having a look at [How to check the exit status using an 'if' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675681/how-to-check-the-exit-status-using-an-if-statement) which provides a few options for how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
git diff --exit-code # exit code will be "0" if no changes
if [ $? -gt 0 ]; then
  echo hello
fi
```

Comment: can you put an explanation as to what the stuff in the square brackets mean? Sorry not the best with bash.

Comment: `$?` is the last exit code.  `-gt` is greater than - I think @paulsm4 simply used it to demonstrate an example operation you could do with the exit code.