# Why isn't the exit code of the `if` statement a failure if the command failed?

Tags: bash, if-statement, error-handling

I thought I know the shell, but I got bitten with unexpected behavior.

Consider this code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
foo()
{
    if false
    then
        echo success
    else
        return
    fi
}

foo || echo failure
```

Now at first glance one would think the `else return` part is superfluous, but it is not. The code as it is outputs `failure`, but when the cited part is removed, then *nothing* is output.

The bash manual explains (for `if`):

> The exit status is the exit status of the last command executed, or zero if no condition tested true.

Somehow I'd expect the `if` to fail when the command had failed.
Imagine where `echo success` stands there are actually dependent commands that make only sense to execute when the main command (`false` here) succeeded.

What is the logic behind that unexpected behavior?

Seen for bash-4.4.
Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63884458/6607497

Comment: Sorry for the many typos!

Comment: *... or zero if no condition tested true.* is the case here.

Answer (score 2):

The `if` statement never actually completes with the `return` statement; the function returns *immediately*, with the exit status provided by `return`. That exit status is the status of the last command prior to `return` to exit, which was `false`.

Without the `return`, the `if` *does* complete, and as documented, the exit status of an `if` command is defined to be 0 if none of the conditions in the `if` clause or any `elif` clause evaluated to true. This makes sense, because the `if` statement successfully determined that none of the `if` or `elif` blocks needed to be executed.

Comment: I know, but wouldn't it make much more sense if `if` would return the exit code of the last command being executed (not the `if`)?

Comment: It *does*, if the last command is in the body of one of the clauses. `if true; then false; fi` has an exit status of 1. If none of the conditions are true, the entire `if` statement is equivalent to an empty statement, which is also defined to have an exit status of 0. (For example, `$()` by itself.)

Comment: `If cmd; then ... fi` can *never* be an empty statement as `cmd` is executed in any case! If `cmd` fails and there is no `else` part, then the last command executed is `cmd`. I'd consider `if cmd; then foo;fi` equivalent to `cmd && foo`. However the latter fails if `cmd` failed.

Answer (score 1):

The bash manual explains (for `return`):

> return
>
> ```
> return [n]
> ```
>
> Cause a shell function to stop executing and return the value n to its caller. If n is not supplied, **the return value is the exit status
> of the last command executed** in the function.

So:

```
if false
then
    echo success
else
    # The LAST command is `false` with exit status 1 !
    return  # Returns 1 - returns failure!
fi
```