# bash: unexpected conditional construct behavior

Tags: bash

I'm a beginner in bash scripting, so some features aren't clear for me, for example this one below.

`man bash` says:

```bash
if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi
          The  if  list  is  executed.  If its exit status is zero, the then list is executed.
          Otherwise, each elif list is executed ...
```

Key information for me is that exit status in `if list` should be `0`.

I execute a command in terminal:

```bash
if [[ /usr/bin/false && 0 ]] ; then echo success ; fi
```

`if list` here is `/usr/bin/false && 0` and I expect, that this command will print nothing because of `/usr/bin/false`, which exit status is always `1`. But **it prints success**, as if the exit status of the `/usr/bin/false && 0` command was 0!

I've checked `/usr/bin/false && 0` exit status separately:

```bash
$ /usr/bin/false && 0
$ echo $?
1
```

Status is `1`, as I expected. But I don't get why `if` statement above executes as if it was `0`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26675681/4722345

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49849957/4722345

Comment: In the example you give, `list` is not `/usr/bin/false && 0`, but `[[ /usr/bin/false && 0 ]]`

Comment: @WilliamPursell Hmm, when I run `[[ /usr/bin/false && 0 ]]; echo $?`, I see `0`. But I'm telling you I'm a very beginner, so I don't understand, why `[[ /usr/bin/false && 0 ]]` gives us `0` and `/usr/bin/false && 0` gives `1`. Please, give a detailed answer in this post, if it is not hard for you.

Comment: The second of the links posted by JBallin is directly on point, because the person there makes the same mistake of using `[` or `[[` when they shouldn't. The answers telling that person to stop using `[[` to wrap the name of a command when they want to test the exit status of that command are exactly the answer you need here.

Comment: The other thing is that it's not clear what you expect `0` to mean. Do you want it to be true or false? If you want it to be false because it's not a positive integer, make it `(( 0 ))`. If you want to to be true because it's the specific value 0, make it `(( 0 == 0 ))`. If you want to to be true because it's not an empty string, make it `[[ 0 ]]`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and JBallin, I've figured it out; you were totally right and I wasn't. My question is marked as duplicated with proposition to delete, and now I cleanly understand why. Thank you for links and answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if [[ /usr/bin/false && 0 ]] ; then echo success ; fi
```

The cause of your confusion is that in this context `/usr/bin/false` is not a command that is run, it is just a string.

The list in question is not `/usr/bin/false && 0`, it is `[[ /usr/bin/false && 0 ]]`, which is `[[` with some arguments.

Inside `[[`, there are two strings (`/usr/bin/false` and `0`) and a control operator (`&&`).

As long as a string cannot be interpreted as an operator, providing a string alone is equivalent to the test `-n string`, which tests that a string is not zero-length.

`[[ /usr/bin/false && 0 ]]` == `[[ -n "/usr/bin/false" && -n "0" ]]`

Both `/usr/bin/false` and `0` are not zero-length.

Therefore the `&&` returns 0 (true).

---

To have `/usr/bin/false` be treated as a command, you would need something like:

```
if /usr/bin/false && [[ 0 ]]; then echo success; fi
```

Comment: Note that in `[[ 0 ]]`, the `0` isn't being treated as a number, just a meaningless string. `[[ 0 ]]`, `[[ 1 ]]`, `[[ true ]]`, `[[ false ]]`, and `[[ wibble ]]` all evaluate as true, because "0", "1", "true", etc are all non-null strings. (As opposed to `[[ "" ]]` and `[[ ]]`, which would both evaluate to false.)