# How to avoid calling external utility (grep) twice while maintaining return code & output?

Tags: bash

I have following Bash function which return property value from Java-style property file. It property wasn't found, it should return non-zero. If found, property's value will be printed & return code must be zero.

```
function property_get() {
    local pfile="$1"
    local pname="$2"
    if egrep "^${pname}=" "$pfile" 2>&1 >/dev/null; then
        local line="$(egrep "^${pname}=" "$pfile")"
        printf "${line#*=}"
        return 0 # success
    else
        return 1 # property not found
    fi
}
```

The question is: how to avoid from calling egrep twice? First exec is for status code, 2nd is for property value. If I use `$(grep parameters)` notation, then grep will be launched in subshell and I can't get it's return code and won't be able to determine success or failure of property searching.

Comment: Why not just get the line, and then check if it was found?

Comment: @matt that's looks like indirect check for me. grep already report it's success or failure by providing us return code and I would like to get advantage of that fact

Comment: Something like `$?`, as per this [how to check the exit status](http://linuxcommando.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/how-to-check-exit-status-code.html)?

Comment: @matt it won't work with `$()`. I need to find a way to capture both exit code from grep & it's output from single grep invocation

Comment: @AndreyBrindeyev Yes it will work. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157938/bash-exit-code-of-variable-assignment-to-command-substitution

Comment: @julien-lopez well, it certainly failing for me: https://gist.github.com/abrindeyev/10a57177b9181dc82f30518a580f1885

Comment: Did you see the difference. It is the local command as stated in Julien's answer.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
...
local line
if line=$(egrep "^${pname}=" "$pfile" 2>/dev/null); then
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As @matt points out, you can just get the line then check the exit status of your command:

```
line=$(...)
if test $? -eq 0; then
  # success
  ...
else
  # property not found
  ...
fi
```

**Edit:**

To summarize:

- You can use `var=$(cmd)`, to set `var` to the standard output of `cmd` and `$?` to the exit status of `cmd`
- With `local var=$(cmd)`, `$?` will be set to the exit status of `local` which is `0` as explained here: [Why does "local" sweep the return code of a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421257/why-does-local-sweep-the-return-code-of-a-command)