# How to capture the Gradle exit code in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, gradle, exit-code

I would like to capture the **return code** of a Gradle task. Here is a small bash script **draft** which executes a tasks:

```
#!/bin/bash

gradlew_return_code=`./gradlew assembleDebug`
echo ">>> $gradlew_return_code"
if [ "$gradlew_return_code" -eq "0" ]; then
    echo "Gradle task succeeded."
else
    echo "Gradle task failed."
fi
```

The script does **not** store the return value but instead the whole console output of the Gradle task.

---

Please note that the example script is a simplification of a more complex script where I need to capture the return value.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157938/bash-exit-code-of-variable-assignment-to-command-substitution

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Exit status is in `$?`. Command substitutions capture *output*.

```
./gradlew assembleDebug; gradlew_return_code=$?
```

...or, if you need compatibility with `set -e` (which I [strongly advise against using](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105)):

```
gradlew_return_code=0
./gradlew assembleDebug || gradlew_return_code=$?
```

...or, if you need to capture both:

```
gradlew_output=$(./gradlew assembleDebug); gradlew_return_code=$?
if (( gradlew_return_code != 0 )); then
  echo "Grade failed with exit status $gradlew_return_code" >&2
  echo "and output: $gradlew_output" >&2
fi
```

Note that I do advise putting the capture on the same line as the invocation -- this avoids modifications such as added debug commands from modifying the return code before capture.

---

However, you don't need to capture it at all here: `if` statements in shell operate on the exit status of the command they enclose, so instead of putting a test operation that inspects captured exit status, you can just put the command itself in the COMMAND section of your `if`:

```
if ./gradlew assembleDebug; then
  echo "Gradle task succeeded" >&2
else
  echo "Gradle task failed" >&2
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

This didn't work for me - at least for Gradle 8.5 - despite the valid output (`Process 'command '.../bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 64`), Gradle does not propagate non-zero exit values from tasks and returns 1 instead.

I used this workaround for my GitLab runner to pass the valid exit code through the standard output:

1. Use `ignoreExitValue true` to make task succeed despite the exit code and print the real exit value:

```
tasks.register('someTask', JavaExec) {
    description 'Some task with unusual exit codes'
    mainClass = 'script'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    // Gradle will ignore non-zero exit value and print it at the end of execution for script to capture
    ignoreExitValue true
    doLast {
        println executionResult.get().exitValue
    }
}
```

2. Execute the task in shell and capture the value  - use `tee` to propagate the stream to both stdout and variable.

```bash
EXIT_CODE=$(gradle -q someTask | tee /dev/tty | tail -n 1 )
```

Using `tee /dev/tty` didn't work for GitLab runner execution so I've managed to fix that by streaming through the file descriptor.

```bash
{ EXIT_CODE=$(gradle -q someTask | tee /dev/fd/3 | tail -n 1 ); } 3>&1

echo $EXIT_CODE
```