# Pass substituted command to function in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to pass a generic function to another function as a substituted command. However, I fail understanding the detail of the evaluation and when the exit_code or the stdout is returned and used.

I wrote this script for testing:

```
#!/bin/sh
# also tested with /bin/bash on ubuntu 22.04 with same result.

# exit code 1, result 
pass_substituted_command() {
  result=$($1)
  echo "$?"
  echo "result: $result"
}

pass_substituted_command "$(echo false)"


# exit code 0, result 
pass_substituted_command() {
  result=$($1)
  echo "$?"
  echo "result: $result"
}

pass_substituted_command "$(false)"


# exit code 0, result false
pass_substituted_command() {
  result=$1
  echo "$?"
  echo "result: $result"
}

pass_substituted_command "$(echo false)"

# exit code 0, result 
pass_substituted_command() {
  result=$1
  echo "$?"
  echo "result: $result"
}

pass_substituted_command "$(false)"

# exit code 0, result 
pass_substituted_command() {
  result=$($1)
  echo "$?"
  echo "result: $result"
}

pass_substituted_command "$(echo 'test'; echo false)"

# exit code 0, result test\nfalse
pass_substituted_command() {
  result=$1
  echo "$?"
  echo "result: $result"
}

pass_substituted_command "$(echo 'test'; echo false)"
```

From the answer [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20157997/5785453) I would expect that all except the last two examples behave as the first one. For the last two, I would expect exit code to be 1 and result to be test each.

Can anybody explain why this is not the case and how I could achive this? Thanks!

Comment: In the 1st, 2nd and 5th variant, you are actually executing something in your function (`$($1)`). In the other variants, you are not even trying to execute something. This alone should already make it obvious, that the cases are not equivalent.

Comment: That's what I say in my question - the questions says "I fail to understand the details of the evaluation [....]". I also write in the comments the outputs to show it's different. However I don't understand why. 
The 1st would make me think it's passed as an argument first and then only evaluated within the $($1)), however, the 2nd contradicts this. The 3rd is making no sense for me at all, if it would be evaluated first and then passed, $1 should be 1 or false - but it seems to be neither.
The question tfherefore Can anybody explain why these differences are and how I could achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `$(....)`, what's inside the parenthesis is interpreted as a command. The command is executed, its stdout is collected, and the whole construct is replaced by this stdout. This is called in bash *command substitution*, and described in the section `Command Substitution` in the man page.

If you take your 1st example, you are calling

```
pass_substituted_command "$(echo false)"
```

which means that bash first executes the command

```
echo false
```

then collects its stdout (which is false), and hence invokes effectively

```
pass_substituted_command false
```

Inside the function, `$1` is bound to the string `false`.

When you do a

```
result=$($1)
```

you execute the command `false`. Since this command does not produce anything on stdout, the command substitution is empty, and `result` is the null string.

Similarily, in your 2nd example, you have a

```
pass_substituted_command "$(false)"
```

which is equivalent to

```
pass_substituted_command ""
```

and $1 is the null string. You assign the null string to `result`.

You can analyze the other variants of your function in the same way.

In the last two cases for instance, `$1` gets bound to a string containing a newline character (since `echo` ensures a newline at the end of the stdout). This string is effectively

```
test
false
```

If you execute this string again (via `$($1))`), nothing is produced on stdout, and `result` will be empty.

In all your examples, the exit code should be zero, since the last command in your function is an `echo`, and there is nearly no way an `echo` would fail (unless someone has closed its stdout, which is not the case here).

Comment: Thanks a lot - this made me find my error in my understanding! I missinterpreted `echo false` to return the same as `false`... 

Anyhow, to pass a function an get its return value and exit code, i just pass it as a string, so:

`pass_substituted_command() { result=$($1 2>&1); echo "$?"; echo "result: $result" }`
`pass_substituted_command "echo test"`

and the 2>&1 makes sure errors are also stored in the result variable.

Thanks again!

Comment: @Agyss: Be careful - dragons here! As soon as you say something like  _return value and exit code_ of a bash function, you need to define what _return value_ means. Functions in bash are more similar to subroutines in, i.e., Fortran, than to functions in most other languages, in that they don't "return a value".